# Geth does nothing but listening

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to setup a simple testnet, and mind some ether to deploy my first contract so I follow [the official geth tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/cli), but I'm stuck at the "run" part and the instructions don't do what I expect.

If I do anything with geth, I get :

```
2200 backend.go:477] server started
2200 server.go:530] Listening on [::]:30303
_
```

And it does nothing but listen. I'm forced to ctrl+C. I want to create a private testnet, so I use this : (just following the tutorial)

```
geth --datadir ~/.ethereum_private init ~/dev/genesis.json
geth --fast --cache 512 --ipcpath ~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc --networkid 1234 --datadir ~/.ethereum_private  console
```

and the first line brings me on the "listen" line again, I don't know what to do from here and I'm not finding any info about that. Is there something I did wrong, am I missing something ?

The only reaction I can get is if I use `geth --mine`, the command line responds that I have no keys in store (which is normal).

(I have also done the wallet tutorial until the "deploy" step)

And I forgot, the geth console returns `'cmd' is not defined` for every single command.

Comment: It seems it's the latest version of Geth that was broken, it seems to work with another one. I'll keep updating.